# Extract JPG urls from Bing or Google search

Tags: url, xidel

Is there anyway to use Xidel to query either Bing or Google image search and then extract all the URL link for images from that search?   I was interested in doing this via the command line using the Xidel.EXE.  Thanks

K

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Great you found Xidel. Great cmdline scraper, but very few people seem to know about it.
Here's a oneliner that scrapes 100 "dogs" image urls of google-images:

```
xidel -s "https://images.google.com" ^
      --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;) Firefox/40" ^
      -f "form(//form,{'q':'dogs'})" ^
      -e "<div class='rg_meta'>{extract(.,'ou.:.(.+?).,',1)}</div>*"
```

BTW, Google actually wants you to use their API, for which you can request an APIkey, but the above command just pretends to be a browser.

Also, if you add --download at the end, it will download all pics. :-)

Comment: For the extraction query you could use `//div[@class='rg_meta']/json(.)/ou`, or more elegantly `for $x in //div[@class='rg_meta'] return json($x)/ou`.

Comment: Yup, both Reino's extraction queries are shorter, easier to understand and probably faster than a RegEx parsing. The great thing with Xidel is that there are many ways to do stuff because it knows (and adds to) so many query languages that you can combine. XPath/XQuery/RegEx(text)/Jsonic/CSS.  As far as I know there is no other programming language or tool that can do all this in a one-liner. It's also very handy with powershell/bash because it knows so many in/output formats, so you can put it in a pipe.